# Activation of Service Principal as Account Owner in the EA Portal via Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface

Our customer wants to use a service principal to generate new subscriptions, so that a malicious employee doesn't have owner access to newly created subscriptions. I already generated a service principal via CLI, but to make him an account owner in the ea-portal the principal needs an e-mailaddress which is of course not existing. I cannot make that service principal an account owner

I already tried to implement to scenario based on the following learn.microsoft.com-entries:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=azure-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/grant-access-to-create-subscription?tabs=rest%2Crest-2

The generation of the service principal was done with:

az ad sp create-for-rbac --name %name_of_the_account%

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an eMail address. An existing account owner under the enrollment must grant the service principal (SP) the "SubscriptionCreator" role.

Step one after the creation of a SP is assigning said role to the SP. Use the REST API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/enrollment-account-role-assignments/put), the existing account owner can log in directly on this page and send the request. You need to set a few properties as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/assign-roles-azure-service-principals#assign-the-subscription-creator-role-to-the-spn), the `billingRoleAssignmentName` among others which is `a0bcee42-bf30-4d1b-926a-48d21664ef71` for the "SubscriptionCreator" role. In the HTTP body you define which SP will get these rights by specifying the `principalId` and `principalTenantId` property.

Afterwards, the SP can create subscriptions under the enrollment programmatically, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription-enterprise-agreement?tabs=rest#create-subscriptions-under-a-specific-enrollment-account) for details.

Answer (score 0):

@NormanPunge The default RBAC role assigned to the Service Principal is Contributor.

You can provide the owner role to your service principal using the below command

```
az role assignment create --assignee <your Service Principal ID> --role Owner
az role assignment delete --assignee <your Service Principal ID> --role Contributor
```

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/grant-access-to-create-subscription?tabs=azure-cli%2Cazure-cli-2#grant-access